# go xml marshalling of attribute without excess struct

Tags: xml, go, marshalling

I'm working on an client to talk to an XML API. Everything is working just fine but I feel the encoder (or my failure to grok it) is forcing me to use additional structs I don't really need.

An example of the kind of request I need to send is something like this:

```
<command_name>
    <prop_1>p1</prop_1>
    <prop_2>p2</prop_2>
    <prop_3 id="prop_3_id"></prop_3>
</command_name>
```

It is worth noting that prop_3 will never have any content within the node and id will be the only attribute present

In order to Marshall this response I am currently using the following two structs:

```
type RefID struct {
    ID string `xml:"id,attr,omitempty"`
}

type CommandName struct {
    XMLName       xml.Name `xml:"command_name"`
    Prop1         string   `xml:"prop_1"`
    Prop2         bool     `xml:"prop_2,omitempty"`
    Prop3         RefID    `xml:"prop_3,omitempty"`
}
```

What I want is to be able to pass in the prop_3 id to requests without having to use the RefID struct. I tried something like this, but it doesn't seem to work with attributes:

```
Prop3  string `xml:"prop_3>id,attr,omitempty"`
```

I know this seems minor but it would just make life easier for anyone consuming my client, if someone can confirm definitively this is not possible then at least I can move on and remove the dirty @TODO next to my code.

Comment: Currently not possible. Long "wanted" feature, never got to production. Related github issues: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/3688, https://github.com/ivankravchenko/go/pull/1

Comment: @icza, thanks for response - at least I can put this to bed for now. Agreed duplicate - a fair bit of searching didn't turn out that particular answer for me.

Comment: Anoter related github issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/3633#issuecomment-66067258

Comment: thanks again @icza - Following through on that link it looks like there may be some movement on this, I might not drop the bone just yet - looks like a mainline commit providing a new way to pick up attributes - I don't think its quite what I was envisioning but might be useful. I will poke a bit further and report back